# Encrypting connection strings in a shell file

Tags: shell-script, encryption

I work in a large organization with dozens if not hundreds of dev teams working on various products, and one of our goals is to try and establish some standards around encrypting confidential information. One of our big struggles is connection information (say to a database) in a config file. For Windows, and specifically .NET applications, we've found an elegant solution with ASP.NET 2.0 and some of the included providers (RSA and DPAPI). Unfortunately, we haven't found a great solution to this problem for our Unix-like systems. So...

1. I'm aware of the the third party library OpenSSL and the rsautl command, as well as the GnuPG solution. Are there any others that come to mind?
2. If no to the above, does anyone have experience with both and could recommend one over the other?
3. It seems to me that both of the above solutions will encrypt an entire script file as opposed to specific elements (like the connection string). Is there any way to encrypt just a specific section of a file?

Comment: Is the question: **How can I encrypt passwords that are used by programs to connect to a database?** ..... If so, some databases offer methods of supplying authentication information and credentials through per user password files or system user authentication rather than using a password stored in plaintext in a config file...  The answer may depend on which database you are using, unless you are looking for a generic encryption method... There are also databases that allow encryption per column, so it's definitely possible to store a list of passwords in an encrypted column in a DB.

Comment: Who are you hiding these strings from, and why? People who already have root access can eventually read everything. Would ssh keys not work? Or why not encrypt the entire system, instead of just a few lines or files? Also, if you're considering making your own DIY encryption scheme vs GPG, you might want to stick with the one with decades of secure tested use (GPG), and especially avoid openssl's `enc` command, see [OpenSSL vs GPG for encrypting off-site backups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247821/openssl-vs-gpg-for-encrypting-off-site-backups)

Comment: @Xen2050 ... I think the OP's problem is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354242/a-better-approach-than-storing-mysql-password-in-plain-text-in-config-file) ...

Comment: @RubberStamp - yes, we're looking for a generic encryption method. While encrypting the plain text password for a DB connection is the primary use case, we want to come up with some generic standards around encrypting any kind of sensitive data in logs and config files. Also, appreciate the link to the other thread as this gives my team some other possibilities to consider.

Comment: >encrypting any kind of sensitive data in logs and config files.  ......... Encrypting snippets of text within a file is possible, but not really practical.  The encrypted word or line is going to need to be decrypted at a certain point. ..... I'm not familiar with ASP.NET, but I found [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/encrypting-connection-strings-in-Asp-Net-2-0/) **ASP.NET 2.0 allows storing connectionString elements within the connectionStrings section in web.config. The web.config section containing connection strings can be encrypted for security.**  .... separate config file.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's what we're doing for our .NET applications on Windows. I was wondering if there was a similar solution for our devs working on products that will run on Unix-like hosts, but it's looking like either OpenSSL or GPG.

Comment: It looks like the .NET solution involves sectioning off the encrypted strings.  This can be emulated with either `openssl` or `gpg` by inserting some delimiter in your files and using a combination of text processing techniques to encrypt the section/s and reinsert the encrypted section in base64 format....  However, it's probably a better idea to utilize a separate file which contains all the connection strings.  Then pull what is needed from that file later.  Remember that transparent encryption is only as secure as where the private key is stored.  For most systems that is on the system.